# One RA vs multiple RA's (investments in general as well)

Tags: investing, retirement, retirement-plan, annuity, south-africa

I am young and trying to work out how I want to get a retirement annuity sorted. **My question is, is it better to put 9 in to one RA, or 3 3 3 in to 3 different RA's?** (here I just use the numbers to explain the ratio of splitting) Personally I like the spreading option, but I am not sure if I am hurting my returns by doing this (hurting my compound interest)

Comment: What country? In the US - annuities are good investments _during_ retirement, usually not _before_ retirement.

Comment: South Africa, I had no idea this matters

Comment: Nine whats get put into the RA?

Comment: @RonJohn Ah sorry Ron, thought it would be obvious but I changed my question. The 9 and 3's are just examples of the ratios. In other words, should I keep everything in one, or split the up into multiples?

Comment: Paul, I wonder if not enough people on this site know the particulars of the South African retirement system.  (The US, at least, doesn't seem to have anything like this.)

Comment: Ah, great haha. Maybe just answer in a general since. Very very long term investments, are they better done as one, or multiple? Very safe long term ones